# Iterate over a List in Java

Tags: java

I have one doubt: can i iterate over a List? I mean a List, not a is-a collection. I know that List is a interface, but it seems to be possible to iterate over a List (returned after convert `"String[]`" using `"Arrays.asList(String[])"`.

Is it possible or am i wrong?

Comment: Well, what have you tried? What have you searched for? Did you look at the API? (Hint: try `enchanced for loop` or `iterate list`.)

Comment: Best way to test doubts is to write code.

Comment: Is that your only doubt? Sorry;-)

Comment: if (myList instanceof Iterable) { System.out.println("It is possible to iterate over a list"); }

Comment: Google : Iterate over list in Java.

Comment: well, read the question please.

I Know how to use for, iterator and etc. I just don't understand why is possible iterate over an interface (which cannot be instantiated). Read before answer ;).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) has [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) as a superinterface, so (if you had a `List<String>` named `list` for example) you could do

```
for (String str : list)
  // do something with `str`
```

This is probably the simplest way to iterate over a list (it's called a *for-each* loop). In fact, you can iterate over any `Collection` like this.

Comment: TY for the answer.

OK, i know that.

But, if List is an interface (which cannot be instantiated), why is that possible? Iterate over an Interface? Or what is that reference (List) pointing to at the moment?

Comment: Well, an instance of any class that implements the `List` interface; whether that's an `ArrayList`, a `LinkedList`, an anonymous class, or any custom class makes no difference - because the class implements `List` it is guaranteed to also be `Iterable` (as I noted in the answer). Therefore, we can iterate over it with a for-each loop.

Comment: So, if i use `"asList"` on `String[]`, it will retun a `ArrayList` or something that IS-A `List` or a raw `List`?

Thank You!

Comment: Correct, it doesn't necessarily have to be an `ArrayList` (because the return type for that method is not `ArrayList` but rather simply `List`) but what it returns will surely be `Iterable`.

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer. I didn't know before that was possible to use a interface to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[The indicated method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) returns a `java.util.List` which is a [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
List yourList = Arrays.asList(yourStringArray);
for (String s : yourList) {
  // do something with s
}
```

or more simply (you don't need a list)

```
for (String s : yourStringArray) {
  // do something with s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a list, an array or an list wrapping an array.  You can iterate over it by using an Iterator with a while loop or for loop, but counting through the indexes, or by using the for each construct.

There is no many ways of doing this and so many examples already I will not add to them.